# layout cshtml not rendering after publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tested an application locally that renders fine on my local machine. When I publish it to a server at work the _layout.cshtml isn't rendering. Their might not be any style rendering at all from the looks of developer tools. Any suggestions because I'm stumped and Google hasn't found me any similar scenarios? I'm using MVC5 with Razor

My view start has

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Edited version....my _layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - XXXXXXXXXXX</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <meta name="Training Module" content="Website for oreintation and traing modules" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <img src="/Images/imgCClogoHorizontal.jpg" style="float: left; padding-top: 10px" />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px">
                @Html.ActionLink("XXXXXXXXXXXX", "Index", "Module", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @*                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>*@
                @*                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>*@
                @*                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Orientation Videos", "Index", "Video")</li>*@
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@Html.Action("Index", "NavigationMenu")
<div class="container body-content">
    <div style="display: inline">
        <div style="float: left">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    </div>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

my bundle.config...

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: with this info no body will be able to help

Comment: Using my crystal ball, I'm going to guess it's something to do with CSS relative paths.

Comment: Where do you want me to start with info?

Comment: 1) Does your rendered html contain the layout content? 1a) If so, are the styles loading to the browser? 2) Is the layout file copied to the server? 3) Are you using areas?

Comment: it does not contain the layout content, styles also don't look like they are being loaded. The layout file is in the shared folder under views in the server. New to MVC dont know what you mean by areas

Comment: after researching i am not using areas. I'm what i guess would be considered mvc 4 with all different controllers, models and views, in those particular folders

Comment: When you bring up your page, and you click View Source, is the first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: <!doctype html> doesnt show up......first line is head and its empty and then body. The body content is there for the most part but its not styled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _ViewStart.cshtml was in the Shared folder so I moved it out one folder and placed in the root folder, "View" and then my layout page rendered across all my views. I must of moved it by mistake and never noticed it. SMH!!!!

Comment: `_Layout.cshtml`  file in an Area of an Asp.net core razor pages also [will not render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75788508/1068538)  If there is no `_ViewImport.cshtml` file inside the `Pages` folder in that area.

Answer (score 2):

You have your navbar content in the `<head>` of the page instead of the `<body>`.  The browser is likely rendering nothing as it doesn't understand.

Comment: +1 good catch. it seems odd this page works properly locally!

Comment: navbar is built out of box in VS2013 when creating "not empty" MVC project. i havent changed its location but only the content with in it.

Comment: ok but the `</head>` tag must be before `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`. The head tag can't contain div. The <head> element can include title, scripts, styles, meta information...

Answer (score 0):

Does your @ViewBag.Title get populated and are you able to see the title on the screen. If so, layout.cshtml is rendering, but your css/js files may not be. Can you check if you are bundling all your resources properly.

Comment: View bag title does not populate and i had organization name next to view bag that i removed from this post and it also doesnt render