# MVC Areas not render _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, azure-devops

I have the MVC project with .NET CORE 2.2
I add Areas in my project it work properly when in the local machine.

I setup CI CD pipeline with Azure Devops, when the application is published successfully. I notice my Areas is not render properly, this below is from azurewebsites.

[image: Screen Shot]

**And this below is display when i debug locally, can someone help. where goes wrong**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: There's not enough information for us to be able to help you. Could you be a bit more specific and add the relevant code? Please refer to [mcve]

Comment: Basically the Areas/Admin is run ok when debug locally, but the CI/CD Pipeline is success, when I hit the URL, It look like the screenshot 1, without _Layout rendering. What kind information do you need for further investigation this issue?

Comment: You are probably missing some css files not being uploaded to the server. Open the console and check for errors or the Network tab to see which files aren't loading.

Comment: From the html inspect, it didn’t render the _Layout, not the css.

Comment: Is the path correct for the _Layout file on publish? and has the file definitely been deployed - maybe check the folder on the deployment target?

Answer (score 1):

I had a rendering issue with a _layout.cshtml file in an Area (my case also the `Admin` area) of the project in ASP.NET 7. The line:

`<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>`
didn't render as:
`<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>`

The issue was fixed after adding a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file into the `Pages` folder inside the `Areas\Admin` folder.  Also the `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` line should be added to the  `_ViewImport.cshtml` file

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on .csproj It include this line, i got no idea how it add this in csproj.
but when i removed from the csproj it work properly.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Areas\Admin\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\Admin\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```