# Azure Pipelines Build do NOT update MVC _layout View file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Azure Pipelines Self-host agent to build and deploy MVC Project and I host the web site on two different servers. The problem is that i have two different shared/_layout view files for each server and I have task which depending on the server (pre defined variable) replaces _layout file content from template (powershell script).

So Pipeline replaces the shared/_layout file content, commit the change, push. And then begin the Build task. When is all finished - Artifact is published, then deployed, the deployed website always looks for the JS Scripts from the OLD _layout file. When I check the Views files in Published project I see the content is correct. It has been replaced correctly.

But when I go to the URL I see that the site still looking for the old JS files.... Why is that?

If I publish the MVC Project manually and then copy the DLL files to the active directory everything works fine. But when the build is from Azure it just do not work. I tried to publish Artifact to local file system instead of Azure, but still the same result.

Why it cannot read the new _Layout view file?

Comment: When you publish the MVC Project manually, do you publish from build agent machine and from the build workspace?

Comment: I publish from local clone of the branch. Outsite Agent work folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the .csproj file in your build source directory to see whether there is content like below, remove them:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

A similar case here [MVC Areas not render _Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739828/mvc-areas-not-render-layout)

Comment: No such content. I suspect it is because i change the content with the Agent.  Probably if I commit manualy the correct _Layout before Azure Pipelne start to wokr it will be fine

Comment: Please try to publish from the build source directory on the build agent machine manually, to see what's the result.

Comment: I actually have partial success. When I go to agent\_work\1\a,  take the Project.zip file from the last Pipeline Build and Extract it in the Active directory everything is fine. The Release pipeline however does not update the content properly. Could this be sometihing with Azure Artifacts? Like the do not get updated properly?

Comment: No, it keep downloading some old one from Azure Artifacts

Comment: Have you checked the release definition? How did you define the artifact when you add it? You may clean the build source directory on the build agent machine and have another try.