# Layout not loaded after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish

I published my project, but unfortunately its layout does not load properly

The head tag of the page is empty and does not see the css references, although I gave the css references inside the project and it works properly in localhost

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check if the scripts on your layout page for your published environment match the same as for Development environment.

Comment: You need to make sure your `_ViewStart.cshtml ` is in the right place.Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788096/layout-cshtml-not-rendering-after-publish).